Ear training to identify specific chord/contrapuntal voicings?
I can comfortably transcribe melodies, identify keys and intervals, and get the rough chord progression for a song by ear. I'm now trying to get to (what I think of as) the next level.
I'd like to be able to identify exact chord/contrapuntal voicings and transcribe those as well. e.g. Where exactly is a jazz pianist/guitarist putting their fingers as they play over some changes, or what notes are all the voices in a choir singing at a certain point in time?
Historically, I have done this by replaying recordings and writing down one voice at a time, or replaying a lot and straining to hear a few notes at once. This doesn't seem like the easiest approach, and I'd like to be more fluent, i.e. to get all the notes down after max 2 or 3 listens (and without needing to focus on one voice at a time).
I'd guess what I need is an approach for recognizing combinations of sounds as single, distinct entities. e.g. "that's a 5-3-1 G", (vs "thats a D, a B a major 6th higher, and a G a minor 6th above that" and then putting them all together).
I'm assuming people have had this same desire/challenge before me, and that there are established ways to name/recognize harmonic sounds in this way. But what are they called, where can I learn about them, and what are the exercises that can help me improve?
Thanks for any advice you can give.

Does this answer your question? How do you recognize open-position chords by ear?

I'm voting for the duplicate but I have a thought that isn't reflected there yet, so I'll add an answer. The short version is: we "fill in" a lot of the gaps of what we hear with what we should expect from the genre and instrumentation. This is true for voicing just as for choice of chords and melody notes.

Hi @Aaron, not really, that's a very specific question about open triads, whereas I'm looking for some kind of more general convention for naming and learning to recognize various chord voicings. Thanks for the link though.

@achalk Are you able to consistently identify close position voicings? If no, then that's a necessary first step. Once close position is easy, I suspect you'll find open position comes more naturally. If yes, then please update your question to address where things go wrong with open position.
